# C# Array of strings contains string part from another array of strings

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a way using LINQ, to find if string from one array of strings contains (partial) string from another array of strings? Something like this:

```
string[] fullStrings = { "full_xxx_part_name", "full_ccc_part_name", "full_zzz_part_name" };
string[] stringParts = { "a_part", "b_part", "c_part", "e_part" }; 

// compare fullStrings array with stringParts array
// full_ccc_part_name contains c_part (first match is OK, no need to find all)
// return index 1 (index 1 from fullStrings array)
```

This is asked rather for educational purpose.
I'm aware that Linq does not magically avoid the loop, instead does it in the background.

Comment: what is the problem of a loop? In fact when you need to do some list-operation you *have* to loop that list in some way, be it explictely using a `for` or whatever-loop or implicetly via some linq-statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Where` + `Any` with string methods:

```
string[] matches = fullStrings
     .Where(s => stringParts.Any(s.Contains))
     .ToArray();
```

If you want to compare in a case insensitive way use `IndexOf`:

```
string[] matches = fullStrings
     .Where(s => stringParts.Any(part => s.IndexOf(part, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0))
     .ToArray();
```

In case you want the indexes:

```
int[] matches = fullStrings 
     .Select((s, index) => (String: s, Index: index))
     .Where(x => stringParts.Any(x.String.Contains))
     .Select(x => x.Index)
     .ToArray();
```

Comment: that internally uses a loop, I´m not sure if this matches OPs problem.

Comment: OP: Mind that while this is not using a _literal_ for-loop, it _will_ loop "under the hood", of course.

Comment: @HimBromBeere: sure it does, i'm sure OP just didn't want to see the loops and see a LINQ way. Of course you have to use loops when you want to look at each item and they are stored in a collection

Comment: The desired answer is the index of the first matching `fullStrings` item (see // in the code block)

Comment: @HimBromBeere While I think, Tim's assumption is reasonable, I also agree with you that OP should clearify.

Comment: The problem with users that ask these kind of question is they often do not realize a loop is used internally and tend to use linq everywhere in their code without any actual **need** for it. I agree your assumption, though.

Comment: ^^ ... or they even think they are being automagically "more efficient".

Comment: I suppose we all have made this assumption at some time, though :|

Comment: @PeterB: I'm not sure if OP just wanted to tell what is the correct string and not that he wants the index. But i'lll edit the answer. Edit: Done

Comment: @HimBromBeere: maybe some really think that LINQ is magic and can return whatever you ask for without actuallly looking at the collections even if i doubt that. Anyway, it can reduce complexity and help to understand your own code later if you use LINQ at the right places. Maybe that's what OP wants

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes, the question was for educational purposes rather than resolving a real problem. I'm completely aware, that this only hides the loop. 

And one more time thanks everybody, didn't expect so many comments so quickly. I'm grateful for that.

Answer (score 1):

You would of course need to use some type of loop to find the index. Here is a solution using Linq.
This will return the first index if a match is found or -1 if none is found:

```
var index = fullStrings
              .Select((s,i) => (s, i))
              .Where(x => stringParts.Any(x.s.Contains))
              .Select(x => x.i)
              .DefaultIfEmpty(-1)
              .First();
```